# Turn a point feature into a line feature

Tags: qgis

How best can I take point items and turn their geometries into lines?
Eg. Each point item becomes a 5m line that starts from the original point geometry.

Comment: what should be other properties ? Direction ? Is it only for display or does the geometry column mandatory have to become a line geometry ?

Comment: @snaileater Hi . The direction is not relevant to me at this stage. I simply have a number of point features with attribute data that would be best suited if they were line features. Individual geometries would be manipulated at a later stage.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only for display purposes u can use the marker symbology/**geometry generator**.

In the expression tab u can then use something like :

```
make_line(make_point($x,$y), make_point($x+dx, $y+dy))
```

dx and dy being the translation u want for the second vertex

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. Although I do think that I need to have a set of features that essentially are line features, rather than visually looking like them..

Comment: You can use the `Geometry by expression` tool to create a new layer using the same expression you used in the geometry generator.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote "*Individual geometries would be manipulated at a later stage.*" I'd like to suggest using a [virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html).

As query use something like

```
Select id, make_line(make_point(x(geometry),y(geometry)),make_point(x(geometry)+55,y(geometry)+77)) as geometry from pointlayer
```

adjust it to your needs.

[image]

`+55` and `+77` is the example offset I used. I am also using a metric projection here so thats in meters. You can also use other expressions from QGIS-Expressionbuilder to generate your line.

The result is a (virtual) layer having geometry. When you save it as .shp file or something else you will be able to edit it's geometry manually.

[image]